# Code is overwriting array

Tags: c

Is there a problem with these samples of code? Whenever there is an X in the spot it still is overwriting an O in the spot if a win can be made. Apparently the if not statement is not working? 88 and 79 are 'X' and 'O' in ASCII.

```
while(i+j<6)
    {
        if (board[i][j]+board[i][j+1] == compXO*2)
        {
            if(board[i][j+2] != (88||79)) 
            {
            board[i][j+2] = compXO;
            won=1;
            break;
            }
        }
        else 
            i++;
    }


if (board[i+1][j+1]+board[i+2][j+2] == compXO*2)
    {   
        if(board[i][j] != (88||79)) 
        {
        board[i][j] = compXO;
        won=1;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare to two different values like that at once, as the expression `88||79` is logical or, and evaluates to `1`, the appropriate way is:

```
if(!(board[i][j] == 88 || board[i][j] == 79))
```

or

```
if(board[i][j] != 88 && board[i][j] != 79)
```

Comment: The second one works though I believe the last end parentheses is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This `if` statement is not doing what you think it is:

```
if(board[i][j+2] != (88||79))
```

It should be:

```
if (board[i][j+2] != 88 && board[i][j+2] != 79)
```

`88||79` is doing a logical or of the values `79` and `88` which will always be `true` which will be equal to `1`, so you are comparing the board element to `1` each time.

Comment: I was wondering if that was it. What does the original statement actually mean?

Answer (score 1):

`88||79` is equivalent to 1. So, your `if (board[i][j+2] != (88||79))` is really equivalent to `if (board[i][j+2] != 1)`.

What you probably want is:

```
if (board[i][j+2] != 88 && board[i][j+2] != 79))
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
if (board[i][j+2] != (88||79))
```

is comparing `board[i][j+2]` with 1, because `(88 || 79)` evaluates to true, aka 1.

Maybe what you're after is:

```
if (board[i][j+2] != 88 && board[i][j+2] != 79)
```

It would be better if you gave names to those otherwise non-obvious numbers (or used `'X'` and `'O'` — there is absolutely no efficiency gain (or loss) from using the character notation, but there is a vast gain in clarity.

```
if (board[i][j+2] != 'X' && board[i][j+2] != 'O')
```

If you have a character that's used to represent 'neither X nor O present', which might be `' '` or some other value (0?), then you could simplify the test to:

```
#define EMPTY ' '

if (board[i][j+2] == EMPTY)
```

which appears to be what you're testing.  If you're not confident that your board is accurate, you should write a validating function which checks that each square has a valid value (`'X'` or `'O'` or `EMPTY`) and that there are not too many `'X'`s or `'O'`s.  Call it at any point where you're worried that it might have changed or be invalid.

Comment: I originally did use 'X' and 'O' but wasn't sure if that was causing the problem so I put them in number form.